# Delete exact matching array from other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

Is it possible to drop an exact matching array out from another array?

Two arrays:

```
let array1: any[] = [[1], [2,3], [1,2]];
let array2: any[] = [[1]];
```

What I want to do:

```
function deleteArrayFromArray(array2) {
  // delete given array2 from array1
}
```

Result should be:

```
array1 or new array --> [[2,3], [1,2]]
```

Is there something like lodash's filter, but with an exact array to array comparison:

```
_.filter(array1, array2);
```

Comment: If the order is important... just use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I know they marked it as duplicate but maybe this will help you in your specific case. 

`function deleteArrayFromArray(array1, array2) {
  return array1.map(JSON.stringify).filter((x) => !array2.map(JSON.stringify).includes(x)).map(JSON.parse)
}`

`deleteArrayFromArray( [[1], [2,3], [1,2]], [[1]])`

a functional approach using es6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter one array and compare object with JSON.stringify with second array and then use `slice` method to delete from one array,

```js
let array1 = [[1], [2,3], [1,2]]

let array2 = [[1]];
//console.log(array1);    
array1.filter(function(obj) {
 // JSON.stringify(obj)==JSON.stringify(obj)
  for( var i=0, len=array2.length; i<len; i++ ){
          if(JSON.stringify(obj)==JSON.stringify(array2[i]) ) {
              array1.splice(i, 1);
             return false;
          }
      }
 return true; 
});
console.log(array1);
```